# HTML - SVG File animation not working on host, but works on local?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an "roulette roll" svg file, but it does nothing. If I tried it on localhost everything was working perfectly! On hosting, it's just like "picture" doing nothing. Question is, how could I fix it?

.svg file code: http://pastebin.com/dsyD3vft

Container:

```
<div class="wheel_container col s6" style="padding: none;">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="wheel.svg" class="wheel" id="wheel">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wheel {
width:100%;
z-index: 0;
display:block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("object").load(function() {
wheelSVG = $("object").contents().find("svg");
spinner = spinner.add(wheelSVG.find("#spin"));
center = wheelSVG.find("#ui ellipse");
centerText = wheelSVG.find("#number");
clearInterval(beforeLoginSpinInterval);
if(!loggedinn) {
    beforeLoginSpinInterval = setInterval(function() {
      currentRotation += 0.25;
      spinner.css("transform", 'rotate('+currentRotation+'deg)');
    }, 20);
  }
});
```

Spin

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="spin">
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M432.3,38.5c-34.2,7.3-68.1,18.3-101.3,33.1s-64,32.7-92.3,53.1l72.2,99.4l-0.4,0.3     c21.6-15.7,45.1-29.3,70.5-40.6c25.3-11.3,51.2-19.6,77.3-25.2l-0.5,0.1L432.3,38.5z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(0.9136 -0.4067 0.4067 0.9135 322.6442 175.6196)" class="st0 st2 st3">14</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M237.9,125.3c-28.2,20.6-54.8,44.4-79.1,71.4s-45.2,55.9-62.7,86.1l106.4,61.4l-0.2,0.4     c13.4-23.1,29.3-45.1,47.9-65.8s38.8-38.8,60.4-54.5l-0.4,0.3L237.9,125.3z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(0.6691 -0.7431 0.7431 0.6691 210.1937 276.5912)" class="st0 st2 st5">7</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M95.6,283.6c-17.4,30.3-32,62.8-43.2,97.4s-18.6,69.4-22.3,104.2l122.2,12.8l-0.1,0.5     c2.8-26.5,8.4-53.2,17-79.5c8.6-26.4,19.7-51.2,33-74.3l-0.2,0.4L95.6,283.6z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(0.309 -0.951 0.9511 0.309 124.1028 456.9215)" class="st0 st2 st6">13</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M30,486.2c-3.6,34.8-3.6,70.4,0.2,106.5s11.3,71,22,104.2L169,659l0.2,0.5c-8.2-25.4-13.9-52-16.8-79.6     s-2.8-54.8-0.1-81.3l-0.1,0.5L30,486.2z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.1045 -0.9945 0.9945 -0.1045 123.8907 608.0349)" class="st0 st2 st7">6</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M52.4,697.9c10.9,33.2,25.3,65.8,43.5,97.3c18.2,31.5,39.2,60.3,62.5,86.3l91.3-82.2l0.3,0.4     c-17.8-19.8-33.9-41.8-47.7-65.9s-24.9-48.9-33.2-74.3l0.2,0.5L52.4,697.9z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.866 0.866 -0.5 200.3061 792.6865)" class="st0 st2 st8">12</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M159.1,882.2c23.4,25.9,49.9,49.8,79.3,71.2c29.4,21.4,60.3,39.1,92.2,53.4l50-112.3l0.4,0.2     c-24.4-10.9-48-24.4-70.4-40.7c-22.4-16.3-42.6-34.6-60.5-54.4l0.3,0.4L159.1,882.2z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.809 -0.5878 0.5878 -0.809 312.469 893.9415)" class="st0 st2 st9">5</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M331.5,1007.2c31.9,14.1,65.8,25.2,101.4,32.8s71,11.2,105.9,11.3V928.4h0.5c-26.7,0-53.8-2.8-80.9-8.6     c-27.1-5.8-53-14.2-77.4-25.1l0.4,0.2L331.5,1007.2z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.9782 -0.2079 0.2079 -0.9781 500.8162 960.7355)" class="st0 st2 st10">11</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M539.8,1051.3c34.9-0.1,70.4-3.7,105.9-11.3s69.4-18.6,101.4-32.8l-50-112.3l0.4-0.2     c-24.4,10.8-50.3,19.3-77.4,25.1c-27.1,5.8-54.2,8.6-80.9,8.6h0.5V1051.3z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.9782 0.2079 -0.2079 -0.9781 651.1284 945.1309)" class="st0 st2 st10">4</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M748,1006.8c31.9-14.3,62.8-32,92.2-53.4c29.4-21.4,55.8-45.3,79.3-71.2L828.2,800l0.3-0.4     c-17.9,19.8-38.1,38.1-60.5,54.4c-22.4,16.3-46,29.9-70.4,40.7l0.4-0.2L748,1006.8z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.809 0.5878 -0.5878 -0.809 826.7827 849.8548)" class="st0 st2 st9">10</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M920.2,881.5c23.3-26,44.3-54.8,62.5-86.3c18.2-31.5,32.6-64.1,43.5-97.3l-116.9-38l0.2-0.5     c-8.3,25.4-19.3,50.3-33.2,74.3s-29.9,46-47.7,65.9l0.3-0.4L920.2,881.5z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.5 0.866 -0.866 -0.5 915.7706 727.7227)" class="st0 st2 st8">3</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M1026.4,697c10.7-33.3,18.2-68.1,22-104.2c3.8-36.1,3.7-71.8,0.2-106.5L926.4,499l-0.1-0.5     c2.8,26.5,2.8,53.8-0.1,81.3s-8.6,54.2-16.8,79.6l0.2-0.5L1026.4,697z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(-0.1045 0.9945 -0.9945 -0.1045 959.8926 558.2834)" class="st0 st2 st7">9</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M1048.5,485.2c-3.7-34.7-11.1-69.6-22.3-104.2c-11.2-34.6-25.8-67.1-43.2-97.4l-106.4,61.4l-0.2-0.4     c13.3,23.1,24.4,48,33,74.3c8.6,26.4,14.2,53,17,79.5l-0.1-0.5L1048.5,485.2z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(0.309 0.951 -0.9511 0.309 931.2808 385.5747)" class="st0 st2 st6">2</text>
</g>
<g>
    <path class="st1" d="M982.5,282.8c-17.5-30.2-38.4-59.1-62.7-86.1s-50.8-50.8-79.1-71.4l-72.2,99.4l-0.4-0.3    c21.6,15.7,41.8,33.9,60.4,54.5s34.5,42.7,47.9,65.8l-0.2-0.4L982.5,282.8z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(0.6691 0.7431 -0.7431 0.6691 834.8956 239.4054)" class="st0 st2 st5">8</text>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M839.9,124.7c-28.3-20.5-59.2-38.4-92.3-53.1s-67.1-25.7-101.3-33.1l-25.5,120.2l-0.5-0.1     c26.1,5.6,52,13.9,77.3,25.2s48.9,24.9,70.5,40.6l-0.4-0.3L839.9,124.7z"/>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(0.9136 0.4067 -0.4067 0.9135 687.3855 145.1121)" class="st0 st2 st3">1</text>
</g>
<g>
    <path class="st11" d="M645.3,38.3c-34.2-7.2-69.6-11-106-11c-36.3,0-71.8,3.8-106,11l25.5,120.2l-0.5,0.1    c26.1-5.5,53.2-8.4,80.9-8.4c27.7,0,54.8,2.9,80.9,8.4l-0.5-0.1L645.3,38.3z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 514.27 118.9369)" class="st0 st2 st12">0</text>
</g>
```

Comment: could you create a fiddle to give us a demo?

Answer (score 1):

If your code was working correctly on localhost and now it does not work on server, I would recommend you checking with your web host if they support SVG files and that the mime type is added.

additionally you could embed the entire svg code in your html thereby saving another call to your server and eliminating the doubt whether webserver supports svg or not.

Also you should save the file as compressed SVG instead of standard illustrator svg

Comment: Everything is on VPS.

Comment: can you see any errors in browser console? is there a 403 or 404 error logged for the svg file request?

Comment: Hmm, if I look that .svg file and console then there is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined" because of addons. If I look that addon .js file, then that part is pointed out: noscript.style.display = 'block';

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: all seems in order. can you show the network panel? open the network panel and reload so as to capture all the requests. then you can filter by `.svg` and check if there are any errors

Comment: is this the request for the `.svg` file? I cannot see any `content-length` headers. Your requests should look like this. https://s18.postimg.org/wvagnk6ah/Capture.png are you sure you have `status-code: 200` and not `304`? if yes then disable cache and reload

Comment: It is 304, how can I "fix" it?

Comment: there is nothing to fix here because nothing is broken. I just wanted to see whether your svg is loading. I am sure that the svg is now loading but its not animating.
I would suggest you open your svg in illustrator and save it as compressed svg http://www.joshuawinn.com/svg-export-settings-for-the-web-with-adobe-illustrator/

Comment: Did that, seems like nothing happened :(

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle to demo it.

Comment: Hmm, how could I do that? If I tried, it said my browser doesn't support svg

Comment: Maybe give a link to your example on your server

Comment: Hmm, I got one website what has same roulette rolling thing. Here is link: http://csgobears.com/

Comment: Hey, do you got any soulution yet?